# Set EntryModel data on an element

Tags: plugin-development, entries, entries-field

I am trying to update the value of an `Entries` field on an `EntryModel`, however I am having a lot of trouble getting it to update correctly.

I've tried allocating both an entire `EntryModel` and its `id` but neither seems to set the value, e.g.

```
$comment = new EntryModel();
$comment->sectionId = $commentSectionId;

$comment->setContent(array(
    'createdBy' => $user // or
    'createdBy' => $user->id
));

craft()->entries->saveEntry($comment);
```

Where `$user` is a valid `EntryModel`.

The comment saves fine, the `createdBy` field just has no value. I guess I am using the wrong data from `$user` but I have having a very hard time finding any thorough documentation around setting different kinds of EntryModel data.

This is the entire bit of code I have, if it helps:

```
class Bugr_CommentService extends BaseApplicationComponent
{

    public function post(EntryModel $user, EntryModel $ticket, $body)
    {
        $comment = new EntryModel();
        $comment->sectionId = craft()->sections->getSectionByHandle('comments')->id;

        $comment->setContent(array(
            'createdBy' => $user,
            'ticket' => $ticket,
            'body' => $body
        ));

        return craft()->entries->saveEntry($comment);
    }

}
```

Comment: Need to set the user id within an array. `'createdBy'=>array($user->id)` or `'createdBy'=>[$user->id]`. Very similar question [can be found here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9569/784).

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald Ohh of course, because the entries field is obviously a list of entries. Sigh, makes perfect sense - thank you.

Comment: Should also be using `getContent()->setAttributes([...])` (or `setContentFromPost()` if coming from post data) instead of `setContent()`. Check out the example I linked.

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald Sure, I'll keep that in mind. This is pretty much a duplicate but it would be nice if there was a more generic thread that covers both this and the linked questions.

Comment: Btw... I assume that 'createdBy' is a custom field? To set the author you would obviously want to use `$entry->authorId = 1;` where 1 is the id of the user/author.

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald Of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a related Element (i.e. related User, Category, Entry, Tag, Asset) the value should be set to an array of element ids (even if there is only one element).

```
public function post(UserModel $user, EntryModel $ticket, $body)
{
    $comment = new EntryModel();
    $comment->sectionId = craft()->sections->getSectionByHandle('comments')->id;

    $comment->setContent(array(
        'createdBy' => array($user->id),
        'ticket'    => array($ticket->id),
        'body'      => $body
    ));

    return craft()->entries->saveEntry($comment);
}
```